# Does helper loads all functions on load in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my helper there is a function ie abc which involves database operations. While we are loading a helper using

```
$this->load->helper('common_helper');
```

will it load all the functions, ie will it perform the db operation in function abc automatically. Or it will perform the db operation while calling the function

```
abc();
```

Comment: RTM → http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

1. It will load all the functions inside your helper. You can call any method without loading this helper again.
2. Yes, you need to call specific method for each tasks you have defined in your method.

Comment: I agree with all the functions wil load automatically, and we dont have to load the same again. But my question is suppose in function abc there is db operation ie select bulk record from db. will this also be called automatically while loading the helper using $this->load->helper('common_helper'); .

Comment: no, if you want to call it automatically, call that function from your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, helper not loads all function on load, its just link up with helper file.
when you call a helper function then load this function.